# Issue with getting OneToMany data in Spring Boot RESTful response

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-boot, one-to-many

I have `Country` and `Language` entity classes having one to many relationship.

Below are the entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_CODE")
    private String code;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    List<Language> languages;
    // getters and setters
}
```

class `Language`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LANGUAGE")
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Country country;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm using `JpaRepository` for CRUD operations. Here is my Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ICountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long>{
    // http://localhost:8081/country/search/findByName?name=India
    // List<Country> findByName(@Param("name") String role);
}
```

And finally my Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/countries")
public class CountryRestController {

    private final ICountryRepository iCountryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CountryRestController(ICountryRepository iCountryRepository) {
        this.iCountryRepository = iCountryRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/country/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Country> retrieveCountryById(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Optional<Country> country = iCountryRepository.findById(id);
    if (!country.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(country.get());
}
}
```

I'm trying to fetch a country details by id and expecting language data will also be populated in JSON response. But the response contains empty languages.

Below are the Hibernate logs:

```
2018-09-01 05:40:07.863 DEBUG 3612 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select country0_.country_id as country_1_0_0_, country0_.country_code as country_2_0_0_, country0_.country_name as country_3_0_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
2018-09-01 05:40:07.863 TRACE 3612 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-09-01 05:40:07.865 TRACE 3612 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([country_2_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [IN ]
2018-09-01 05:40:07.865 TRACE 3612 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([country_3_0_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [India]
2018-09-01 05:40:07.865 TRACE 3612 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [com.learning.springboot.model.Country.languages#1]
2018-09-01 05:40:07.875 DEBUG 3612 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select languages0_.country_id as country_3_2_0_, languages0_.language_id as language1_2_0_, languages0_.language_id as language1_2_1_, languages0_.country_id as country_3_2_1_, languages0_.language_name as language2_2_1_ from language languages0_ where languages0_.country_id=?
```

Below is the response I'm getting:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "India",
"code": "IN ",
"languages": [],
}
```

Please guide me what am I doing wrong? I'm running queries printed in logs and they are giving me expected results but response has empty language list.

**Edit:**

Earlier I was having two languages per country in the database. I removed one language and response is coming fine for one language. But in case of multiple languages, language in response is coming as empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OneToMany relationship is Lazy by default, so you could set it to Eager as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country {

     // other fields

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Eager ,mappedBy = "country")
    List<Language> languages;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: thanks @MohammadReza Alagheband it worked.But it is also working with fetch = FetchType.Lazy